# Upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 fails

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

Tried to upgrade my computer from 13.04 to 13.10, but directly after pressing the upgrade, a couple files appear to download, and then the window disappears and nothing happens...

I tried it from the terminal window and this is the output (same result)

```
jessijo@halesite3:~$ update-manager

Checking for a new Ubuntu release

authenticate 'saucy.tar.gz' against 'saucy.tar.gz.gpg' 

extracting 'saucy.tar.gz'

Real-time signal 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, try this:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```